# How can i get a '*' ladder?

Tags: c, for-loop

I want to add more * for each line but it appears only 1 * for each line.
so confusing

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int number;
  scanf("%d",&number);
  for(int i = 1 ; i <= number ; i++)
  {
    printf("*\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

```
This is my output
5
*
*
*
*
*
```

```
This is output I want
5
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Comment: So far you've got a loop and in that loop you are only trying to print one star. You need to think about what to do inside that loop to print an increasing number of stars as i increases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest a j loop printing from 1 to i stars. After said loop, but inside the outer, put a newline.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number;
    if (scanf("%d",&number) == 1 && number > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 1 ; i <= number ; i++)
        {
            for (int j=1; j<=i; ++j)
                fputc('*', stdout);

            fputc('\n', stdout);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```